# Проектирование автоматизированных систем

Tags: автоматизация, база-данных

В этом семестре у нас была курсовая работа по предмету "Базы Данных". Суть этой курсовой работы заключалась в проектировании автоматизированной системы какой-либо предметной области. Нужно было провести её системный анализ, придумать организационную структуру предприятия, продумать требования к системе - что конкретно она должна автоматизировать, какие запросы к ней будут строиться. После этого нам нужно было спроектировать инфологическую модель данных, преобразовать её в датологическу, провести нормализацию бд. Затем нужно было логически завершить проект: создать физическую схему бд для конкретной субд (которую тоже нужно было выбрать самостоятельно), а так же написать клиентское приложение, отвечающее требованиям того системного анализа из первой главы.

Сразу скажу, что работа показалась мне не самой простой, но свой отл. я уже получил. В качестве СУБД я выбрал mysql, клиент писал на php, а схему бд строил в mysql workbench.

Теперь, внимание, вопрос: как сделать всё это проще? Я потратил изрядное количество времени даже не на саму бд, а именно на клиентское приложение, что на самом деле не соответствует цели курсовой работы! Многие из моих одногруппников использовали связку C# и MSSQL, некоторые что-то другое, меня же интересует, какая связка была бы проще всего для реализации? Что-то такое, что написало бы за меня 90% кода, а мне надо было бы всего лишь немного покликать мышкой :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имхо: самая удобная связка - это Delphi + Interbase

быстро осваивается и способствует быстрому созданию БД и приложения :)

InterBase 2009 позволяет создавать БД без использования запросов - просто используя диалоговые окна. + Интербейс изначально разрабатывался для связки с Delphi, что позволяет, используя буквально 4 компонента и без особых усилий, отобразить данные из БД в твоем  приложении.

Comment: Ну, я еще ответов хочу :)

Answer (score 0):

на вашем месте я бы выбрал noSql бд (couchdb к примеру, сам использую). было бы оригинально и интересно. тем более для работы с ней предоствлен restful интерфейс и взаимодейстовать очень просто. да и самому может интересно будет - nosql, map reduce.